# Python : How to run postgres pl/sql query from python script with arguments

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to run below postgres sql from python script with arguments it's not working but when I fire this query directly to DB it's working fine-

```
sql_query = text("""DO $$                  
                        BEGIN 
                            IF EXISTS
                                ( SELECT 1 FROM data_check WHERE bid = :bid AND first_nid = :first_nid
                                  AND (((first_datetime - :first_datetime) >= '-00:30:00'::interval) AND ((first_datetime - :first_datetime) <= '00:30:00'::interval))
                                )
                            THEN
                                UPDATE data_check SET second_nid = COALESCE(NULLIF(second_nid, ''), :second_nid), 
                                second_datetime = COALESCE(second_datetime, :second_datetime), 
                                third_nid = COALESCE(NULLIF(third_nid, ''), :third_nid), 
                                third_datetime = COALESCE(third_datetime, :third_datetime) WHERE bid = :bid AND first_nid=:first_nid
                                AND (((first_datetime - :first_datetime) >= '-00:30:00'::interval) AND ((first_datetime - :first_datetime) <= '00:30:00'::interval));
                            ELSE
                                INSERT INTO data_check values (:bid,:first_nid,:first_datetime,:second_nid,:second_datetime,:third_nid,:third_datetime);
                            END IF;
                        END
                    $$""")
kwargs['engine'].execute(sql_query,{"bid": str(row['bid']), "first_nid": str(row['f_nid']), 
                                    "first_datetime": row['Date/Time'], "second_nid": str(row['s_nid']), 
                                    "second_datetime": row['Date/Time_1'], "third_nid": str(row['t_nid']), "third_datetime": row['Date/Time_2']})
```

Also when I am trying to run only below piece of code(only ELSE part from above) it's working fine -

```
sql_query = text("""INSERT INTO data_check values (:bid,:first_nid,:first_datetime,:second_nid,:second_datetime,:third_nid,:third_datetime)""")

kwargs['engine'].execute(sql_query,{"bid": str(row['bid']), "first_nid": str(row['f_nid']), 
                                    "first_datetime": row['Date/Time'], "second_nid": str(row['s_nid']), 
                                    "second_datetime": row['Date/Time_1'], "third_nid": str(row['t_nid']), "third_datetime": row['Date/Time_2']})
```

Please let me know where am I doing wrong OR is there any other way to run this code. Thank you.

I am using python 3.8.10 version. Not working means, it's not giving any error but it's not updating the data. I am not sure that it is the right way to pass the parameter if we are using same parameter again and again in the query.

Comment: 1) What Python adapter/driver and version are you using? 2) Define not working? Include complete error message/traceback. **ADD information as update to question**.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I have updated the question.

Comment: 1) I was looking for driver and version being used by `kwargs['engine'].execute()`. 2) Look at the Postgres log and see what is hitting the database when the command is run. 3) Named parameters `:<some_name` can be reused in a query.